# Turn off Excel AutoTyping/AutoCasting for ever

Tags: excel, typing

If I load a CSV into Excel with the area code "DEC10" in it, it becomes a date automatically. If I then explicitly cast it to text it becomes 40513. I have many more examples like this. Does anybody know how I can get control of my own typing? I am not interested in a solution for this particular example or a work around for certain cases. I want Excel auto typing switched off for ever, for every file. So only if I say the cell is of a type Excel is allowed to cast it. Does anybody know how to accomplish that?

I am asking on stackoverflow because this is exactly the type of functionality that software developers would hate.

Comment: Don't open the csv file directly with excel. Import it and you will be able to specify the data types for each column without Excel doing it first.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.